# How to change *just* the padding of a button in html on iOS

Tags: ios, css

I have an html page with a button and I want to get rid of its padding.  The obvious

```
padding: 0px !important;
```

didn't work.  Writing

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
padding: 0px;
```

did, but it got rid of all the other iOS-like formatting.

Everything works fine on desktop.  This happens on iOS.  I haven't tested Android.

Is there any way to change just the padding without everything else?  Is there any way to save a copy of the style so that I can restore it?  I'm happy with javascript-based solutions (including d3, for any difference that makes).

Answer (score 0):

My current solution (which I am not happy with) is approximately the following javascript/d3:

```
button.style('padding','0px');
if (button.style('padding-left')!='0px') {
  button.style('-webkit-appearance', 'none')
        .style('padding', '0px')
        .style('background', 'linear-gradient(white,#999)')
        .style('border-radius', '10px');
}
```

Which makes the button look kind of like an iOS button, but not really, and does nothing on desktop chrome or firefox, though I'm not sure there isn't a browser this will break.